# How can i use ui button and ui toggle in a script to create/destroy objects on another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Hierarchy i have a Canvas and under it as childs i have a ui button and ui toggle. On the button i attached a script with a onclick event.

The idea is when i click the button depending on the toggle state false/true decide if to just create more gameobjects or destroy first all the old gameobjects and create new.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GenerateObjectsButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InstantiateObjects instantiateobjects;
    private bool toggleOnOf;
    public Toggle toggle;

    private void Start()
    {
        instantiateobjects = new InstantiateObjects();
        toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
            {
                MyListener(value);
            });
    }

    public void MyListener(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            //do the stuff when the toggle is on
            toggleOnOf = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //do the stuff when the toggle is off
            toggleOnOf = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnButton()
    {
        if (toggleOnOf == false)
        {
            instantiateobjects.generateObjectOnTerrain();
        }
        else
        {
            instantiateobjects.DestroyObjects();
            instantiateobjects.generateObjectOnTerrain();
        }
    }
}
```

The InstantiateObjects script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    public int objectsToInstantiate;
    public bool parent = true;
    public bool randomScale = false;
    public float setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax;
    public float setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax;
    public float setTandScaleZMin, setRandScaleZMax;
    public bool generateNew;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;
    private int numberOfObjectsToCreate;
    private GameObject objInstance;
    private GameObject[] createdObjects;
    private string objname;

    public void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        numberOfObjectsToCreate = objectsToInstantiate;

        objname = prefab.name;
        MyCustomEditor.TagsAndLayers.AddTag(objname);

        generateNew = false;
        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void DestroyObjects()
    {
        if (createdObjects != null && createdObjects.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < createdObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                DestroyImmediate(createdObjects[i]);
            }
            createdObjects = new GameObject[0];
        }
    }

    public void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);

            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Generate random x,y,z scale on the terrain
            float randScaleX = Random.Range(setRandScaleXMin, setRandScaleXMax);
            float randScaleY = Random.Range(setTandScaleYMin, setTandScaleYMax);
            float randScaleZ = Random.Range(setTandScaleYMax, setRandScaleZMax);

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            //Generate the Prefab on the generated position        
            objInstance = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);

            if (randomScale == true)
                objInstance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(randScaleX, randScaleY, randScaleZ);

            if (parent)
                objInstance.transform.parent = this.transform;

            objInstance.tag = objname;
        }

        createdObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(objname);
    }
}
```

The problems i'm facing now are:

In the InstantiateObjects when i click the button i'm getting null exception on the line:

```
createdObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(objname);
```

createdObjects is null. Except the first time i'm running the game then it's not null but then each time when i click the button it's null.

Second problem is that i need to change the toggle state to false then click the button true click the button false click the button and only then  it's getting the DestroyObjects method.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be updating the array as the reference are the same. Reset the array to null at the start of each iteration and see if that works.

Comment: The problem is on this line not sure why: for (int i = 0; i < objectsToInstantiate; i++) first time i'm running the game the value of objectsToInstantiate is 5 as it is set in the inspector. But then each time i click the button no matter the toggle state the value of objectsToInstantiate is 0.  Not sure why it's 0 when i click the button.

Comment: And about reset it to null the array each iteration didn't solve the null problem. Maybe it's null since objectsToInstantiate value is 0. Not sure.